# Apache lucene inverted index

Tags: search, lucene, inverted-index

Does Lucene index use tf-idf as weights? Is it possible to define your own statistics and weights for each document, and "plug" them into Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default scoring algorithm incorporates tf-idf, and is fully documented in the [TFIDFSiilarity documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

There are a number of ways to customize the scoring of documents.

- The simplest and most common is to incorporate a boost, either on a field at index time, or on a query term when querying.
- Many query types modify the scoring used for that query.  Examples include [ConstantScoreQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html) and [DisjunctionMaxQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html).
- The `Similarity` you use defines the scoring algorithm.  You could select a different one (ex. [BM25Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html)).
- You can implement your own `Similarity`, Usually by extending a higher-level implementation such as `DefaultSimilarity`, `TFIDFSimilarity`, or `SimilarityBase`

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this example. It may help help you to know how you can bring custom changes in indexing process

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html

Comment: [link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) problem aside, I don't see anywhere in that example where document scoring is really addressed.